# how to set up configural model for longitudinal CFA?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I have 12 survey questions (Qs) that were asked during pre- and post-term survey. So I want to do the longitudinal CFA to see whether there was a difference between factor models for pre/post-term surveys

12 survey questions are broken down into 3 latent variables:

Anx =~ Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4

Bel =~ Q5 + Q6 + Q7 + Q8

Eff =~ Q9 + Q10 + Q11 + Q12

so the same questions were asked in pre and post-term surveys.

I was wondering about how to build the configural model :

1. Model each factor separately for pre and post-term:

   ```
   overall.model.Bel <- '
   Bel.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Bel.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post
   '

   overall.model.Anx <- '
   Anx.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Anx.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post
   '

   overall.model.Eff <- '
   Eff.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Eff.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post
   '
   ```
2. Or I should do it all at ones:

   ```
   overall.model.Bel <- '

   Bel.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Bel.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post

   Anx.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Anx.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post

   Eff.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Eff.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post
   '
   ```
3. any other things I should add or modify?

Then build the model

```
overall.fit <- cfa(model = overall.model,
                   data = master, 
                   meanstructure = TRUE)
```

4. Also, out of curiosity, can I use `library(equaltestMI)`  to do longitudinal CFA? or that one is only for multigroup CFA ( I am not entirely sure what is the difference in the steps between two, except that for multigroup one the groups are independent of each other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to test measurement invariance over time, you need your 2nd model but with additional constraints so that lavaan knows which indicators are actually the same item measured repeatedly. This is easy to do with `semTools::measEq.syntax()`. It takes your model, adds required pieces of syntax according to settings you make, and fits the model.

In your example that should work as follows:

```
overall.model.Bel <- '

Bel.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
Bel.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post

Anx.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
Anx.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post

Eff.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
Eff.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post
'
rep_factors <- list(Bel = c("Bel.pre","Bel.post"),
                    Anx = c("Anx.pre","Anx.post"),
                    Eff = c("Eff.pre","Eff.post") )
fit.config <- semTools::measEq.syntax(configural.model = overall.model.Bel,
                                      data = master,
                                      longFacNames = rep_factors,
                                      return.fit = TRUE,
                                      meanstructure = TRUE)
```

Comment: yes, I know about further steps on testing metric invariance and etc. I just have a question about setting up the original model

Comment: That is what I assumed. The `longFacNames` argument is for the original model (and also the further ones in invariance testing). It is **not** an invariance constraint but makes lavaan handle the repeated factors and indicators correctly.

Comment: So there is no point in doing the analysis separately for Bel factors and then repeat steps for Eff and Anx, right?

Comment: The crucial part is that you include the .pre and .post parts of each factor simultaneously and define them as repeated. Whether you want to test all three factors at once or separately is an entirely different question. Please excuse me, if I misunderstood that. If you want to test invariance independently for each of them, make three separate models. If you want to test overall measurement invariance (e.g. if these are three facets from one questionnaire) then you keep them in one model.

Comment: Also, because I am doing longitudinal CFA and not multigroup CFA, this is an appropriate functions/steps to use?(sorry, I am completely new to this topic)

Comment: Yes, the `longFacNames` takes care of that.

Comment: thank you!Sorry for so many questions! also am I correct that for configural model: all I need to check is the goodness of fit criteria (CFI, Rrmsea) and also whether my variance is positive and squares is positive

Comment: A statistician would probably disagree, but as a researcher in psychology, the pragmatic answer is "yes". Usually, CFI, Rmsea, and sometimes SRMR and TLI are taken as sufficient indicators that your model fits. The chisquare test is also usually reported but it gets easily p < .05, even with decent fit if you have a rather large sample. But also look at your regression coefficients, whether their size and sign makes sense.

Comment: can you suggest any sources where i can see how  weak/strict and strong invariances is set up in semTools::measEq.syntax? I found this library: library(equaltestMI) which automatically produces all teh models, but i don't think it works for longitudinal CFA, only multigroup ones

Comment: Have a look at `help("measEq.syntax")`. You can make restrictions for invariance along repeated measures by setting the `long.equal` argument. If you know the `group.equal` argument for multigroup invariance testing, it works nearly the same (see `help("lavOptions")`).